# Golang constant struct key

Tags: php, json, data-structures, go

In PHP we can do something like:

```
if ($env == "dev") 
  define("key", "key")
else
  define("key", "secret")

// json ouput
//{ key : "value" } or { secret : "value" }
```

How do I properly translate above PHP approach to GO?

I was thinking of something like:

```
if *env == "dev" {
  type response struct {
    key string
    ...50 more keys that should also be different depending on env
  }
} else {
    secret string
    ...50 more keys...
}
```

But I guess that is not only wrong but would also create a huge repeated code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a struct type holding the common part of your data structure, and you may create new types *embedding* this and only adding the deviating new field. So there is no code repetition of the common part of the data structure:

```
type Response struct {
    F1 string
    F2 int
}

func main() {
    for _, env := range []string{"dev", "prod"} {
        if env == "dev" {
            type Resp struct {
                Response
                Key string
            }
            r := Resp{Response{"f1dev", 1}, "value"}
            json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(r)
        } else {
            type Resp struct {
                Response
                Secret string
            }
            r := Resp{Response{"f1pro", 2}, "value"}
            json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(r)
        }
    }
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/a0gwZQ5Wuv)):

```
{"F1":"f1dev","F2":1,"Key":"value"}
{"F1":"f1pro","F2":2,"Secret":"value"}
```

Note that you may also use the same `Response` value if they are the same for the 2 use cases:

```
comResp := Response{"f1value", 1}
if env == "dev" {
    type Resp struct {
        Response
        Key string
    }
    r := Resp{comResp, "value"}
    json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(r)
} else {
    type Resp struct {
        Response
        Secret string
    }
    r := Resp{comResp, "value"}
    json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(r)
}
```

You may shorten the code above by using anonymous struct and not creating a local variable (not necessarily more readable):

```
if env == "dev" {
    json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(struct {
        Response
        Key string
    }{comResp, "value"})
} else {
    json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(struct {
        Response
        Secret string
    }{comResp, "value"})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable:

```
var key = "secret"
if env == "dev" {
   key = "dev"
}
```

Use that variable when creating a map to serialize to JSON:

```
m := map[string]interface{}{key: "value"}
p, err := json.Marshal(m)
if err != nil {
   // handle error
}
// p contains the json value.
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/KrPUR750Kw)

Comment: is there a better way? I have inner structs.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question depends on your actual use case. Here are 3 ways to achieve what you ask:

1. Use `map[string]interface{}` instead of struct
2. Use different struct types (as in the example from the question)
3. Use a single struct type that contains fields for both "dev" and "prod" environments, use "json:,omitempty" and populate only necessary fields before marshalling to JSON.

Comment: I was thinking of 2 and 3, but it seems a bit dirty. 1 wouldn't work because I have inner structs that has inner structs that also require changing of keys depending on environment. also, some of this is db result.

Comment: I agree that neither of 2 and 3 is particularly nice. However your requirement doesn't sound clean either. From my experience having different behavior in dev and prod is a receipt for disaster ;)

Comment: Actually this is to obfuscate the json response. Like instead of a key that says "user_info", it will be some random string on production. This is for a game api. And yes, the json is then encrypted.